# Hibernate JPA deadlock

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that is being modified in a transaction. After the modification I use the `entityManager.flush()` method but the transaction is not committed. In another transaction I recover the modified entity using `READ_UNCOMMITTED` isolation. I modify the entity and I try to commit the transaction but it does not work. I get a deadlock. Is there a way to unlock the entity from the first transaction so that I can commit the second transaction with the entity modified?

Comment: Paste relevant code.

Comment: Why are you not committing the first transaction and instead resorting to READ_UNCOMMITTED?  Committing or rolling back the transaction would resolve your issue

Comment: I know that but I have to run an action that may not require to commit the modifications. If so at the end of the first method i call TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(); The purpose of the second transaction is to set a flag on the entity while the action is running

Comment: The purpose of the second transaction is to set a flag on the entity while the action is running so that another user is forbidden to use the same entity for a similar action

Comment: Oracle does not support READ_UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: This sounds like a re-design is needed to use Oracle properly.  Another reason I hate ORMs.